# [SQL]How to calculate valid VIP no. per month?

Tags: sql

I want to  calculate valid VIP no. per month.
There is a VIP table with `vip_card_no,create_date,expire_date`

**The result set should be like that:**

```
period   |   valid vip number
june2016         20
july2016         18
august2016       30
.....
march2017        40
april2017        30
```

(period is a range selected by user.For example,user selects june2016 to april2017 this time)

Expired vip card should be excluded.
E.g a vip card created on 20170321 and it will expire on april2017 .
It will be counted in march2017 but not counted in april2017

**The problems are**

1.I don't know how to group by period since the the time range is a variable
2.I tried to write an Accumulated query,but I don't know how to eliminate the expired data.

something like that

```
select t1.date, COUNT(t2.vip_card_no) as AccumulateNoOfCases
FROM vip t1
join vip t2 on t2.date <=t1.date
group by t1.date;
```

I have spent a whole on it and I hope anyone could help me!!
A Ton of Thanks!

Comment: Plz tag your RDBMS. Plz add your data (sample data) that you want to get that desire result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Teris, you have not provided any sample data, it's difficult to solve any problem without proper information.

I've tried to solve it, and I've created a `Table` according to your description. Inserted some sample data. I've considered your description:

> Expired vip card should be excluded. E.g a vip card created on 20170321 and it will expire on april2017 . It will be counted in march2017 but not counted in april2017.

I've counted VIP card based on **create_date**. Please check this:

**Sample Data**

```
Insert Into VIPTable Values('0000','02/15/2017','02/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('1111','03/15/2017','03/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('2222','03/16/2017','03/16/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('3333','04/15/2017','04/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('4444','04/15/2017','04/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('5555','04/15/2017','04/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('6666','05/15/2017','05/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('7777','05/15/2017','05/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('8888','06/15/2017','06/15/2018')
Insert Into VIPTable Values('9999','06/15/2017','06/15/2018')
```

**SQL**

```
Declare @periodStart DateTime, @periodEnd DateTime
Set @periodStart = '01/01/2017'
Set @periodEnd = '12/30/2017'

Select 
    Convert(Char(4), create_date, 100) + Convert(Char(4), create_date, 120) As Period,
    Count(vip_card_no) As AccumulateNoOfCases
From VIPTable 
Where create_date Between @periodStart And @periodEnd
Group By Convert(Char(4), create_date, 100) + Convert(Char(4), create_date, 120)
Order By AccumulateNoOfCases Desc
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you csharpbd,but what I want is to get the accumulate number.Finally, I decide to do this by Coding. Btw,thank you very much!